# Sliding Session Expiration with ServiceStack Authentication on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, servicestack

When using ServiceStack authentication with ASP.NET MVC, I wanted to implement a sliding session expiration. After some help from @mythz, I got it working. For any who want to do the same, see my answer for my final implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my final implementation for a sliding session when using ServiceStack authentication in ASP.NET MVC...

```
public class SlideSessionExpirationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var ssController = filterContext.Controller as ServiceStackController;
        if (ssController == null) return;

        // Get session and re-save to slide/update the expiration date
        var session = ssController.ServiceStackRequest.GetSession();
        if(session != null && session.IsAuthenticated)
            ssController.ServiceStackRequest.SaveSession(session, AppHost.SessionExpiration);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

...where `AppHost.SessionExpiration` is a `static readonly TimeSpan` that I declared in `AppHost.cs`. To use it, you can slap the attribute on a controller or method via `[SlideSessionExpiration]` or you can add it in via a global filter (like I did) inside `FilterConfig.cs` via...

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    /* ... other filters ... */
    filters.Add(new SlideSessionExpirationAttribute());
}
```